# What is the logic behind dividing arrays of double precision matrix to a large number before sending that matrix to a solver?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, fortran

I am given a code which divides the members of [A] in [A]{X}=[B] to 10^4 when assembling matrix [A]. 
Then it also divides the results array to this number to calculate correct value.
I cannot understand why this should be done? Does double precision has limitation on numbers of integer it can hold; so the maker of this code wanted to increase number of float digits? Or maybe he misunderstood the conception of double precision?

Comment: What means "assembling"? where is the code? Is it C++ or Fortran? why both tags? Will you add tags for all languages in which one can encounter a matrix?

Comment: @VladimirF By assembling I mean the process of adding members aij to the matrix [A] with corresponding i & j.

Comment: Program is both in C++ and Fortran.

Comment: You should post the piece of code showing the operation. Obviously, just dividing the matrix does not change any possible ill-condition.

Comment: It does influence the accuracy of some floating point operations. E.g. Adding 1 to. 0000345 is more accurate than adding 1 to 5e50.

Comment: @VladimirF actually, it can aid some possible ill conditions - for example overflow and as rubenvb said, accuracy.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yes, but he proposes some special operations, while the OP mentioned just a matrix multiplication. That's why I asked for more code in the first comment.

Comment: It depends on the algorithm used to compute "results array".  Some fast algorithms with poor stability properties for matrix inversion (or solving a set of linear equations) are sensitive to the presence of very large or very small values even if the matrix `A` is not ill-conditioned, and scaling can mitigate effects of round-off errors in those cases.  The needed scaling factor in such cases depends on `A` and `B` though - so a fixed value of `10^4` seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing by some constant will not improve the accuracy of the solution as floating point numbers have an exponent representation. Thus scaling by some large number will to a large degree affect the exponent and to a minor degree the significant bits.
The numerically hard part when solving is adding floating point numbers of different orders of magnitude, as this will affect the number of significant bits. However, this does not get affected by a global scaling as the difference of exponents remains the same. Similarly, division, multiplication and square root does not get affected.

What does affect the solution is using different scaling factors,e.g. enforcing the diagonal of a symmetric A to be one. However, this mostly helps with iterative solvers, while cholesky decomposition and similar will only be affected to a minor degree.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is hard to say.

Sometimes scaling was done for IO reasons rather than computational reasons.

If the '*1E-4'  is single precision then it is likely done to discretize the incoming data, and the computations can be in double precision following that.

Obviously seeing code can help.